# select option not working laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, drop-down-menu, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 select a default value for select option is not working

ex:

```html
 <select name="browsers" id="browsers">
          <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer </option>
          <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
          <option selected value="Chrome" selected="selected">Chrome</option>
          <option  value="Opera">Opera</option>
          <option  value="Safari">Safari</option>
      </select>
```

not selecting chrome

why could be the reason for that?

Comment: It does seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/6grngaL7/ and Laravel does actually change the html (I don't even know how you output this html).

Comment: how can laravel change the html?

Comment: it should be **does not** Im very sorry for the confusion

Comment: this definitely works. whats your laravel code?  giving an example of working code, and asking why some code we can't see doesn't work like it, isn't helpful.

Comment: please explain your question because i didn't get your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work although you have unnecessary `selected` (it's not necessary to have both `selected` and `selected="selected"`).

If in your case default value is not selected, you should definitely run this with JavaScript turned off. It's quite possible you have some script or JavaScript library that changes default selected value.

Comment: thats right i found that a javascript library is the reason for that thank you

Comment: @Omneyael-meligy Glad I was able to help :)